# Predictable network interface names with BusyBox

Tags: network-interface, ethernet, busybox, interface

I want to map each hardware NIC to a specific linux network interface (`ethX`) persistently, as currently when an ethernet cable is reconnected, it picks an interface seemingly at random. This is trivial with either [systemd or udev](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkInterfaceNames), but BusyBox does not seem to have a built-in way to do this.

In `/sys/class/net`, the symlinks from `ethX` -> `../../devices/platform/soc/XXX.bus/XXX.ethernet/net/ethX` never change.

I have tried using `nameif`, but this only maps MAC -> interface, and the MAC address is hardcoded in u-boot for each ethX, and is not representative of the actual NIC's MAC.

**EDIT:** This question will remain unanswered for now, because while I still haven't found a reliable way to map NIC -> interface in this embedded BusyBox environment, in my case, the hardware itself is also misbehaving in a way that cannot be solved with software alone.

Comment: can you elaborate what's the issue with [nameif](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/networking/nameif.c)? busybox probably doesn't offer anything else.

Comment: U-Boot has the `ethaddr` and `eth1addr` environment variables which provide a mac address for each of the `ethX` network interfaces in linux, but are not in any way related to the hardware itself. e.g. `eth0` will always have the `ethaddr` MAC address, regardless of its physical NIC.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify that your MAC addresses are random and not actually the MAC of the hardware. Maybe also explain why since that seems very strange to me, but I don't know embedded systems. That is essential information that needs to be in the question, not hidden in a comment.